# How can I delay the ng-init method until my scope Variable finished loading?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project I have a table with multiple cells. In each cell I have a dropdown menu with an initial value. When the page load, I call a function in `ng-init` which returns the correct value for this dropdown menu.

My Problem is, that this function depends on a value I get through an asynchronus call to a server. That means sometimes (if the table is large), the necessary data is loaded **after** the ng-init. This way I can't initialize my dropdowns correctly.

So basically I just need a way to be sure that when ng-init is called, all data has already been received from the server.

Normally I would use a $scope variable to simply update the view after I got all the data from the server, but I can't do it here, because I would need a $scope variable for each cell in the table and the table has dynamic width and heigth.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Here is a brief code example of what i mean:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <md-select ng-model="connectionType"
             ng-init="connectionType = ctrl.getConnectionType(person1.id, person2.id)"
             placeholder=""
             class="md-no-underline">

            <!-- Options -->
 </md-select>
```

Javascript to load the data from the server:

```
dataService.getPersons(curView, function(result) {
  var persons = JSON.parse(result);

  if (persons.length) {

    for (var i = 0;i < persons.length; i++) {
      $scope.persons.push(persons[i]);
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    }
    });
```

Javascript to init the dropdown:

```
self.getConnectionType = function(id1, id2) {

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.persons[i].sourceId === id1&& $scope.persons[i].id2=== activityId) {
                return $scope.persons[i].connectionType;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please add the javascript and html you are using, particularly what occurs after the call resolves

Comment: @NathanBeck I just added some code examples, hope this helps

Comment: Move the initialization code to inside the controller and call it after the data arrives from the server. The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates.  This [tangles conerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of Model and View making, the code more difficult to understand, debug, test, and maintain. You should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope

Comment: @georgeawg I'll try that, thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity what callback-based API are you using to get data from the server? In general callback-based APIs should be converted to return AngularJS promises. That conversion should be done inside the service so that the controller does not need to do `$scope.$apply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the good comment above, don't use `ng-init` if you can help it (which you can, since you can initialize everything you need within your CTRL as soon as it's instantiated). Simply combine both the init of the $scope.persons and the init of the dropdown connectionType.

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function() {
  var init = { 
     connectionType: function(id1, id2) {
       angular.forEach($scope.people, function(person) {
         if (person.sourceId == id1 && person.id2 == activityId) {
           $scope.connectionType = person.connectionType;
         }
       });
     },

     people: function() {
       dataService.getPersons(curView).
         then(function(response) {
           // depending on what response brings back, my APIs return a 'data' property for each response
           $scope.people = angular.copy(response.data);

           if ($scope.people.length > 1) {
             var person1 = $scope.people[0],
                 person2 = $scope.people[1];

             // set up the connectionType between person1 and person2
             init.connectionType(person1.id, person2.id);
           }
         });
      }
  }

  // gets called when CTRL is initialized;
  init.people();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

U could use a $scope variable with ng-if="" on the table and only display it once you have all your data?

Comment: I have tried that, but the problem is that ng-init will be called, even if the table is hidden. So it will display the table after all data is loaded, but with the wrong values because it doesn't call ng-init again

Comment: Get rid of ng-init its not best practice, hide the table until you have the data then show it with a ng-if. You dont need ng-init.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        //$scope.init(); Your loading method
    }, 500)

});
```

Here you can call your init method

Comment: This just calls the init function after the document is loaded, which is already happening at the moment.

Comment: inside this angular.element, write a $timeout function before calling that init function. It may help

Comment: The use of `$timeout` is a **code smell**, a symptom of a more fundamental problem. Avoid `$timeout` and seek a more robust solution.